# My implementation to a linked list, no need to set self back to head?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

as an assignment during software engineering studies i have to implement my own list type in python, i did that using a linked list.

From my past experience whenever i use a line like

> self = self.next

I must first save my head node, than in the end assign head back to self.

In this linked list implementation i totally forgot about it but everything seems to work fine.

Anyway i need help not with 'how to' do something, i just want to understand how does it work without keeping and assigning the head node back, hope it's fine, thanks!

```
class MYList:
def __init__(self,*args):
    numargs = len(args)
    self.value = None
    self.next = None

    if(numargs == 0):
        pass
    elif(numargs == 1):
        self.value = args[0]
    elif(numargs == 2):
        self.value = args[0]
        self.next = MYList(args[1])
    else:
        self.value = args[0]
        self.next = MYList(*args[1:])

def get_value(self,k):
    i=0

    while(i<k):
        self = self.next
        i+=1

    return self.value

def set_value(self,k,v):
    i=0

    while(i<k):
        self = self.next
        i+=1

    self.value = v

def len(self):
    i=0

    while(self.next!=None):
        self = self.next
        i+=1

    return i+1


def append(self, *args):
    if(len(args) == 1):
        v=args[0]
        if(self.get_value(0) == None):
            self.set_value(0, v)
        else:
            i = 0

            while(self.next != None):
                self = self.next
                i += 1

            self.next = MYList(v)
    else:
        v=args[0]
        if(self.get_value(0) == None):
            self.set_value(0, v)
        else:
            i = 0

            while(self.next != None):
                self = self.next
                i += 1

            self.next = MYList(v)
            self.append(*args[1:])


def print(self):
    if(self.value == None):
        print("List is empty!")
    else:
        amount = self.len()
        for _ in range(amount):
            if(_ < amount-1):
                print(self.value,end=',')
            else:
                print(self.value)
            self=self.next

def pop(self,*args):
    if(len(args) == 0):
        count = self.len()
        head=self

        for _ in range(count-1):
            self = self.next

        v = self.value

        self = head

        for _ in range(count-2):
            self = self.next

        self.next = None

        return v

    elif(len(args)>1):
        raise Exception("Enter a key to pop only!")

    else:
        k = args[0]

        count = self.len() - 1

        if(k>count):
            raise Exception("Key too high!")
        elif(k==0):
            v=self.value
            self.value = self.next.value
            self.next = self.next.next
            return v
        else:
            head=self

            for _ in range(-1,k-1):
                self = self.next

            v = self.value
            temp_next = self.next

            self = head

            for _ in range(-1,k-2):
                self = self.next

            self.next = temp_next

            return v
```

Comment: Why would the last node in a linked list need to link back to the head? That'd create a circle, or at best, make for a harder-to-test-for sentinel at the end (where `None` would be a better choice).

Comment: My question is about all the functions that use the self=self.next line,
i'm trying to understand how everything is still alright after it even though i'm not assigning the head back to self.

Comment: `self` is *just another variable* in the functions; you could just use `node = self` then `node = node.next` if that's clearer. As long as the *rest* of the function doesn't need access the original node from which you started, it is fine to rebind `self`.

Comment: Use `for i in range(k): self = self.next` to get to node k.